# ASP.NET application works on localhost server, on remote returns 403 and 404 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've got project written in asp.net (net 4.5) which publishes on localhost server successfully and I have access to all functions.

Today I tried to publish it on remote server. I did it and it worked good. Then I wanted to do some changes, afterwards I wanted to move it to another site so in IIS menager I created new site, deleted my project from Default Web Site and published project to recently created site. Something went wrong so I restored everything to initial state and published again to default web site and at the moment application doesn't work.

When I input in web browser address http:// SERVER/ i got 403 error but when I try for example http:// SERVER//api/tablica/zdarzenia/?od=0&do=10000 or any other subpage I get 404. No additional information is visible to me and I haven't access to any logs or something. I have no idea what have I done wrong with it. Some ad

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Solution can be found there: http://notebookheavy.com/2012/05/21/404-error-on-asp-net-4-5-on-iis-7/